# Why is the introduction different for the video and streaming versions of Lamar's Humble?

Tags: song-lyrics, kendrick-lamar

The video version of Kendrick Lamar's single Humble begins with the following three lines:

> Wicked or weakness
>   You gotta see this
>   Waaaaay (yeah, yeah!)

However, the version of the song on streaming sites like spotify opens with three different lines:

> Nobody pray for me
>   It's been that day for me
>   Waaaaay (yeah, yeah!)

Why are there two different versions of the song?

Comment: I'm asking this because I wanted to ask a question about the line "Wicked or weakness", but I realized that that specific line wasn't in all versions of the song.